# Basic: performing surgery on a ruined power sander cable

Tags: repair

there's still a lot of snow outside, so i tried using my power sander on the porch. It worked for a bit, then i tried to figure what went wrong and found that i sanded the power cable.

I tried uploading the image, yet it says the image is too big...the power sander sanded down the insulation and cut the copper wiring.

What is an easy way to fix this? I'll need a soldering iron and some electrical tape, but will this be enough?

Comment: You will need a mult-meter to test resistance know what prong on the plug goes to which wire goes to which prong BEFORE you cut the cord. Buy a replacement wall plug and cord, chop off the damaged portion, strip the wires, crimp butt splices to connect the cables together then heatshrink the whole thing.

Comment: I would try to open it up and replace the entire line cord up to (and including) probably Faston type terminals, retaining the strain relief. There may be tear down videos for your brand of sander. You should not need a soldering iron, just a crimping tool. This would be a more appropriate question for the DIY SE.

Comment: You were using your power sander for snow removal?

Comment: I would suggest cutting the cord off where it is sanded through, install a new plug and use an extension cord until you can get a replacement cable.

Comment: lol, no ron byer! I was sanding a table with an imperfect cut job. I disagree about forum, cuz im just trying to figure out how to fix a cable, not really do anything myself...if you want to get technical about it.

Comment: "*I disagree about forum, cuz im just trying to figure out how to fix a cable, ...*" I'm afraid that this site is for electronics **design** questions and repair questions are specifically not on-topic. See the [Help] pages for details.

Comment: If the damage is more than 8 inches from the sander, then cut it there and put on a 3-prong plug. Then you have a sander with a foot long cord that plugs into a small extension cord.

Comment: `figure out how to fix a cable, not really do anything myself` ... @Novelty lol ... fixing a cable **is** doing something ... btw, this site is not a forum ... it is a Q&A site

Comment: You can set the resolution of images on your phone or camera lower to produce smaller file sizes.  If you change photos to JPEG format the site will allow you to post relatively huge images as well.  If you need a tool for cutting, editing and resizing images or converting their file types, check out GIMP.  You need a laptop or desktop to run it, but it's free.  You can get editing tools for your phone too, although I'm not familiar with them.  Overall I'd agree this is a better question for DIY.SE because of the basic level.

Comment: That said, I'd be confident repairing the cable in at least 3 ways.  By preference, I'd open the casing of the tool as Spehro suggests and simply mimic the existing install with a brand new cable.  Usually power tools are easy to disassemble but in the case that it wasn't, I'd repair the cable inline with rubber tape(special electrical tape, bonds to itself, high insulation, creates a cushiony layer and heat shrink tubing.  The repair itself I'd be confident with either solder joints or butt splice connectors.  I'd stagger the connections so they aren't side by side.

Comment: From being in the industry, I've overall developed the feel that it's better to spend a few extra dollars(fully replace cable) when possible to produce a better result, but in practice I've seen well done joints with roughly equal service life to the original cord that lasted for years.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bodge it using a soldering iron and electrical tape.  The tape will wear away as you use the sander, leaving live wires exposed.

Either replace the entire cord, or use a properly designed insulated flex connector.